# how to limit log size in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

In my server application I'm creating a log file of size 5kb. If I exceeds 5 kb of file size , I have to overwrite the old contents with the help of new contents.
If you have any ideas just share with me.

I also need implementation of this technique in **qt**.

I've found out some examples in c++, but using boost library, with which I'm not familiar, can you help me on implementation in qt.

```
std::ostream & libLogging::FileRotationLogSink::GetCurrentStream( 
    std::string::size_type required )
{
    if ( static_cast<std::string::size_type>(m_CurrentStream.tellp( )) + 
        required > m_Limit ) {
        m_CurrentStream.close();
        // remove old backup
        if ( boost::filesystem::exists( m_BackupPath ) ) {
            boost::filesystem::remove( m_BackupPath );
        }
        // backup current logfile
        boost::filesystem::rename( m_LogFilePath, m_BackupPath );
        // open new logfile
        m_CurrentStream.open( m_LogFilePath );
    }
    return m_CurrentStream;
}
```

Comment: You seem confused; what is the issue of using boost in your project?

Comment: I haven't used boost but rather found it as an example, there is no necessity of using it, I just want to implement it in qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example implementation:

```
#ifndef FILEROTATIONLOGSINK_H
#define FILEROTATIONLOGSINK_H

#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

namespace libLogging {

class FileRotationLogSink
{
public:

    explicit FileRotationLogSink(size_t Limit = 5 * (1 << 10));
    QTextStream &GetCurrentStream(size_t required = 0);

private:

    size_t m_Limit;
    QString m_LogFilePath, m_BackupPath;
    QTextStream m_CurrentStream;
    QFile m_File;

    void openStream();
};
}

#endif // FILEROTATIONLOGSINK_H
```

with related cpp

```
#include "FileRotationLogSink.h"

libLogging::FileRotationLogSink::FileRotationLogSink(size_t Limit) :
    m_Limit(Limit),
    m_LogFilePath("log"),
    m_BackupPath("bak")
{
    m_File.setFileName(m_LogFilePath);
    m_File.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    m_CurrentStream.setDevice(&m_File);
}

QTextStream& libLogging::FileRotationLogSink::GetCurrentStream(size_t required) {

    if (m_File.size() + required > m_Limit) {
        m_File.flush();
        m_File.close();

        // remove old backup
        if (QFile::exists(m_BackupPath))
            QFile::remove(m_BackupPath);

        // backup current logfile
        QFile::rename(m_LogFilePath, m_BackupPath);
        m_File.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    }

    return m_CurrentStream;
}
```

example use:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "FileRotationLogSink.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    libLogging::FileRotationLogSink log(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        log.GetCurrentStream() << "line " << i << endl;
}
```

yields in log

```
line 92
line 93
line 94
line 95
line 96
line 97
line 98
line 99
```

and in bak

```
line 79
line 80
line 81
line 82
line 83
line 84
line 85
line 86
line 87
line 88
line 89
line 90
line 91
```

Comment: Why openStream() method isn't used or it's not necessarily?

Comment: Sorry, I removed it from cpp, since the binding  `m_CurrentStream.setDevice(&m_File);` can be done at once, but forgot to remove from header.

Comment: Okay, also what of a QTextStream &GetCurrentStream() method, am I suppose to call it in the main, why not to call it in constructor?

Comment: Because that call enables checking the file overflow limit. That's the core purpose of this snippet, i.e. reuse QTextStream formatting capabilities while transparently switching logging target device.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the last what you said.

Comment: it's an application of `data hiding` principle of OOP: when you need to access the functionality (the formatting capabilities of QTextStream, via operator<< ), the logger can enforce the file size limiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `boost::filesystem::<functions>` with `QFile::<functions>`. Check the documentation to see usages and exact signatures.

Comment: Well, there is QFile::exists(const QString &filename), QFile::remove() and QFile::rename() methods thank you for that, but what of a "static_cast<std::string::size_type>(m_CurrentStream.tellp()" is that related to QTextStream?

Comment: It's simple a cast between possibly incompatible types. C++ is a very type strict language.